# Login in Django built in authentication system with Vue - What should I return after login(request, user)?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-authentication

I am trying to develope a SPA with Vue in the frontend and Django (without REST framework) in the backend.

My view requires the user to be logged in with the @login_required decorador. I also have the sign_in view to login the user, but I don't know what I should return to the frontend after the login(request, user).

My `views.py`

```
@csrf_exempt
def signin(request):
    email = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        ???


@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def usinas(request):
    do stuff...
```